# Applying module CSS to page

Tags: plugins, css

I built a module with custom CSS. I'm not sure why the CSS isn't being applied, although it seems like the page is loading the CSS file (when I view source in a page, I can see my custom CSS file, and when I open that link, the content is what it should be). The div class name is pretty custom, so I don't think it's being overwritten.

Code in module:

```php
    function hbc_comicCanvas() {
        wp_register_style('hbc_comicCanvas', plugins_url('css/hbc_comicCanvas.css',__FILE__));
        wp_enqueue_style('hbc_comicCanvas');
        wp_register_script( 'hbc_comicCanvas', plugins_url('js/comicCanvas.js', __FILE__));
        wp_enqueue_script('hbc_comicCanvas');
    }

    add_action( 'admin_init','hbc_comicCanvas');

    function insert_default_content($content) {
        $content = "
      <div id=\"hbc_drawingPanel\">drawingPanel id</div>
        <div class=\"hbc_drawingPanel\">drawingPanel class</div>
        <canvas style='height:500px;width:500px'>woot</canvas>
        ";

        return $content;
    }
    add_filter( 'default_content', 'insert_default_content');
```

And the content of the CSS file:

```css
    div #hbc_drawingPanel{
      background-color: purple;
    }
    div .hbc_drawingPanel{
      background-color: purple;
    }
```

Thanks for any help. I've looked at a bunch of suggestions, but nothing has panned out so far.

Comment: Why are you using `wp_normalize_path`? Also how is the register and enqueue code being called? If you registered the style you don't need the extra parameters in `wp_enqueue` just the handle/first parameter like the docs say. That's also not how `add_filter` works, `add_filter` expects a function/callable or the name of a function as the second paramter

Comment: You shouldn't be using it, `wp_enqueue` and `wp_register` script and style functions expect a URL, and URLs are always `/`. Likewise, in PHP you can use `/` and it will work everywhere, not just Linux TLDR always use `/` even on Windows. Also code in comments doesn't work, can you edit your question to include that code? Note that's still not how filters work, filters ***always*** return something, basic beginners filters 101. Right now your code should be generating lots of PHP warnings and errors, and your CSS won't have anything to work on because of the incorrect use of filters

Comment: Also, you didn't answer my question about how your enqueue functions are being called, this is super important information, you need to share it

Comment: I updated the question. Hopefully included the info you need. Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to remove wp_normalize_path